# Rails Routing Precedence favors the first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-routes

So Ive been working on a rails project that defines two different create actions in the same controller. **Here's my controller:**

```
class SmsSendsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @at = SmsSend.new
    @contact = Contact.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end
  def create
    @at = SmsSend.create(sms_params)
    if @at.save!
    @con = current_user.contacts.find_by(id: @at.contact_id)
    AfricasTalkingGateway.new("trial-error").sendMessage(@con.phonenumber, @at.message)
    end
  end
  def new_all
    @at = SmsSend.new
    @contact = Contact.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end
  def create_all
    @at = SmsSend.create(sms_params)
    if @at.save!
    current_user.contacts.each do |c|
      AfricasTalkingGateway.new("trial-error").sendMessage(c.phonenumber, @at.message)
    end
    end
 end

  private
  def sms_params
    params.require(:sms_send).permit(:mobile, :message, :contact_id)
  end
end
```

In my

> routes.rb

file, Ive used both custom and resourceful routes to define routes for the first and the second new/create actions:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  get 'sms_sends/new_all', to: 'sms_sends#new_all'
  post 'sms_sends', to: 'sms_sends#create_all'
  resources :contacts
  resources :sms_sends
  root 'contacts#index'
end
```

So both post actions will work if and only if its routes are placed before the other. Is there a way I can get rid of the precedence? Or where am I going wrong?

Thankie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So both post actions will work if and only if its routes are placed
>   before the other.

That is how you should define for the routes to work. Because the routes that defined in the `routes.rb` will be compiled from **top-to-bottom**. So if your *custom routes* gets **preceded by** *resourceful routes*, then the custom routes **will conflict** with your resourceful routes.

> Is there a way I can get rid of the precedence?

Define them as **collection routes** like so,

```
resources :sms_sends do
  get 'sms_sends/new_all', to: 'sms_sends#new_all', on: :collection
  post 'sms_sends', to: 'sms_sends#create_all', on: :collection
end
```

The above will generate routes with path helpers like below

```
sms_sends_new_all_sms_sends   GET    /sms_sends/sms_sends/new_all(.:format)   sms_sends#new_all
sms_sends_sms_sends           POST   /sms_sends/sms_sends(.:format)           sms_sends#create_all
```

For a **better readability**, you can change your custom routes like so

```
resources :sms_sends do
  get 'new_all', to: 'sms_sends#new_all', on: :collection
  post 'create_all', to: 'sms_sends#create_all', on: :collection
end
```

This will generate the path helpers like below

```
new_all_sms_sends             GET    /sms_sends/new_all(.:format)      sms_sends#new_all
create_all_sms_sends          POST   /sms_sends/create_all(.:format)   sms_sends#create_all
```

Comment: Yesss, this creates a different prefix for the create_all POST action! It's Perfect. Thank you much Pavan.